# How to intersect two query sets in django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have two queries. One of them has sold product id and sale amount, other one has product id and product price.

```
query_product = Model1.objects.filter(...).values_list('ProductID', 'ProductPrice')
query_sale = Model2.objects.filter(...).values_list('SaleProductID', 'ProductAmount')
```

I want to calculate IF SaleProductID = ProductID, Sum(F('ProductPrice')*F('ProductAmount'). However, I could not find how to do that with query. Note: Model2 has foreign key to Model1.

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you!

EDIT: I want to display the total amount at the admin site in PBGelenSiparis class .Here is the translated full model;

```py
        class PBUrun(models.Model):
            PBUrunNu = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Product Code')
            PBUrunName = models.CharField(verbose_name='Product Name', max_length=200)
            PBUrunPrice = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Product Price', max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

        class PBGelenSiparis(models.Model):
            pburun = models.ForeignKey(PBUrun, verbose_name='Choose Product',  on_delete=models.CASCADE )
            PBGelSipNu = models.AutoField(verbose_name='Order Number', primary_key = True)

            def GelenSiparisTutari(self):
                find_ordered_products = PBGelenSiparisUrun.objects.filter(pbgelensiparis_id = self.PBGelSipNu)\
            .values('pburun_id')

                order_product_price = PBUrun.objects.filter(PBUrunNu__in = siparis_urunlerini_bul).values_list('PBUrunNu','PBUrunFiyat')
                order_product_amount = PBGelenSiparisUrun.objects.filter(pbgelensiparis_id = self.PBGelSipABNu).values_list('pburun_id','PBGelSipUrunAdet')

        class PBGelenSiparisUrun(models.Model):
            pburun = models.ForeignKey(PBUrun, verbose_name='Choose Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE )
            pbgelensiparis = models.ForeignKey(PBGelenSiparis, verbose_name='Order', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            PBGelSipUrunAdet = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Order Quantity')
```

Comment: Are these two models related by a foreign key? Can you share both models

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Model2 has fk to Model1. I have added the full model.

Comment: Model2 == PBGelenSiparisUrun and Model1 == PBUrun, Right?

Comment: Actually, it is like Model1 == PBUrun, Model2 = PBGelenSiparisUrun and Model3 == 'a model with order amount'. However, your subquery advice might help. I will try and post the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, IntegerField

class SQSum(Subquery):
    output_field = IntegerField()
    template = "(SELECT sum(PBGelSipUrunAdet) from (%(subquery)s) _sum)"

accumulated_quantity_subquery = SQSum(
    PBGelenSiparisUrun.objects.filter(
        pburun=OuterRef('id')
    ).values("PBGelSipUrunAdet")
)

queryset = PBUrun.objects.annotate(
    total_quantity=accumulated_quantity_subquery,
    amount=F("PBUrunPrice") * F("total_quantity")
)
```

This will Annotate amount for each Product.